# jquery regex replace substring inside a known pattern

Tags: jquery, regex

Could you help me out how to replace anything between "666666&r=" and "&u" in the img src below ?

```
img src="img.php?&w=300&b=a&n=666666&r=3m&u=domain.com" class="graph"
```

Existing attempt

```
$("#changeimg").change(function() {

    $('.graph').each(function(index) {

       //var sub = t.replace(/^.*666666&r=(.*)&u=*$/, '1y'); ??

       $(this).attr("src", sub);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work nicely:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/([&?]r=)[^&]*/, '$11y');
```

It will replace the `r=` parameter regardless of whether it is at the beginning of the querystring, or in the middle (like in the example you posted)

Answer (score 1):

```
t.replace( /^(.*666666&r=)([^&]*)(&u=.*)/, "$11y$3" )
```

Example and proof at https://regex101.com/r/M8nDNA/1

Answer (score 0):

```
var sub = $(this).attr('src').replace(/&r=.*&/, '&r=1y&');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers !!!

This is working now :

```
$("#changedate").change(function() {
    var sel = $("#changedate").val();
    $('img').each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('src').replace(/([&?]r=)[^&]*/, '$1' + sel));
    });
});
```